# Is it wrong to call Command.Execute or how to rewrite in a better suited way

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have some long running task being executed when I click Login button that causes the `LoginCommand` to fire.

I also call this `LoginCommand` in `OnAppearing` of my ViewModel by calling `LoginCommand.Execute()`.  I would like to call some function preferably in order to accomplish this.  Is there a good way of doing this that is cleaner?

Here is what I have on my `LoginViewModel` which is Derived from `BaseViewModel`.  My `BasePage` calls the `OnAppearing`

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual void OnAppearing() { }
}


public class LoginViewModel: BaseViewModel
{

    public override void OnAppearing() {
        // is there a better way than calling the LoginCommand itself?
        LoginCommand.Execute(this);
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {      
                var validationResult = await SomeLongRunningValidation();
                if (!validationResult.Authenticated) 
                {
                    await navigation.DisplayAlert("Error", "Authentication failed.  Try again?", "Yes", "No");
                }
             });    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your command handler to separate method (that handler you pass to constructor of Command) and call it directly.

Comment: @Evk thanks for this suggestion. I actually tried to add just a normal method with async but it requires it also be a Task.  What's the correct way of going about moving this logic into it's own method correctly?

Comment: @JessicaS Evk's suggestion is accurate. You would need to have a Task. Encapsulate everything in the handler in it's own method and call it from within the command handler. you can also call it from the  on appear. Can you show more of the `LoginViewModel`? Like its declaration. What  type is it derived from?

Comment: @Nikosi I added BaseViewModel part above.  Basically I call OnAppearing from BasePage to trigger the ViewModel to raise this event. I just don't know how to go about correctly moving the logic into a Task method without freezing the app.

Comment: Remember that you should try to avoid `async void` methods, but when you have to use them (like in this case) - _always_ wrap the whole thing in try catch block and do something meaningful with exception if it happens (what you pass in `Command` constructor in your question and in answer below is also async void).

Comment: @JessicaS when you have some time I would suggest reading [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) to get some guidelines on how and when to use async/await. It will come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion made in the comments is accurate.

First extract the code in the command handler and encapsulate it into it's own async method. Have the command handler call it when invoked. The extracted method can also be called from other methods like `OnAppearing`. To avoid blocking you want to keep the code async. You can create an async event handler to handle calling the  async method when the event is raised.

```
public class LoginViewModel: BaseViewModel {   
    private event EventHandler Appearing = delegate { };

    public override void OnAppearing() {
        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = async (sender, e) => {
            Appearing -= handler; //Unsubscribe from event
            await LoginAsync(); // non-blocking async call
        };
        Appearing += handler;//Subscribe to event
        Appearing(this, EventArgs.Empty);//raise event
    }

    private ICommand loginCommand = new Command(async () => { 
        await LoginAsync();//non-blocking async call
    });
    public ICommand LoginCommand {
        get {
            return loginCommand;
        }
    }

    private async Task LoginAsync() {
        var validationResult = await SomeLongRunningValidation();
        if (!validationResult.Authenticated) {
            await navigation.DisplayAlert("Error", "Authentication failed.  Try again?", "Yes", "No");
        }
    }
}
```

Version without the delegates

```
public class LoginViewModel: BaseViewModel {

    public LoginViewModel() : base() {
        Appearing += handler;//Subscribe to event
    }

    private event EventHandler Appearing = delegate { };

    private async void handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Appearing -= handler; //Unsubscribe from event
        await LoginAsync(); // non-blocking async call
    }

    public override void OnAppearing() {
        Appearing(this, EventArgs.Empty);//raise event
    }

    private ICommand loginCommand = new Command(async () => { 
        await LoginAsync();//non-blocking async call
    });
    public ICommand LoginCommand {
        get {
            return loginCommand;
        }
    }

    private async Task LoginAsync() {
        var validationResult = await SomeLongRunningValidation();
        if (!validationResult.Authenticated) {
            await navigation.DisplayAlert("Error", "Authentication failed.  Try again?", "Yes", "No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikosi.  Would it be possible not to do all the subscriptions in the OnAppearing? Or is it required to have a delegate to do this correctly?

Comment: @JessicaS, That could be set up in the constructor. I just did it there to keep the code short. Could have just as easily used an event handler method. If you want to avoid the delegates. I did not know what the rest of your class looked like so used what was given.

Comment: @Nikosi  So would it be valid to not use the Appearing like you have and just call     public override void OnAppearing()
    {
      EventHandler handler = null;
      handler = async (sender, e) => {
        await LoginAsync(); // non-blocking async call
      };     
    }

Comment: @JessicaS No. You have to raise the event. Take a look at the updated version.

Comment: And what is the purpose of event handler here?

Comment: @Evk to allow the use of an `async` handler. as event handlers are the exception to the rule about `async void` which wont be able to be done on `OnAppearing` mehod. It is the safest way to not have any exceptions swallowed.

Comment: But you have `async void handler`, so seems you changed one async void to another, and added  some code of top. Why not just `async void OnAppearing() { await LoginAsync();}`?

Comment: @Evk because `OnAppearing` is not an event handler. It is a normal void method. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: @Evk to get rid of the async void in the command handler you can also raise the event from there. Would need to remove the unsubscribe so that it can be called multiple times.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me. You create absolutely artificial event handler which _only_ purpose is to follow that "rule", but you don't change anything. You use async void method in both cases. If do it like that I can create dummy event every time I'd like and they say - "hey, I'm using event handler so my async void is fine". In this case you are also reacting to event (event of form appearing) so you have no choice anyway, but there is no need to try to hide it behind "event handler".

Comment: @Evk I see what Nikosi is doing now. Because like he mentioned I have a normal event that I could not await inside.  If you have a better approach we can always learn from that would be good :)

Comment: @JessicaS you can await inside `OnAppearing()`, just mark it with async: `public override async void OnAppearing()`. You should always try to avoid having `async void` but here you have no choice anyway.

Comment: @Evk That makes sense. I just have other things in the OnAppearing that now such as clearing ObservableCollection and filling adding to them so I would like to keep this on UI.  I will keep the approach Nikosi suggests as this will at least separate the logic of calling once and also place anything there that requires await. I appreciate your suggestion though - thank you

Comment: @JessicaS you can then move Appearing event to BaseViewModel and fire it there from OnAppearing, because if OnAppearing belongs to it then event belongs there too (and can be useful for all models). And don't forget to vote up answers that helped you :)

Comment: @Evk I just saw this - Sorry.  My BaseViewModel just has virtual methods such as public virtual void OnAppearing() { } that is being raised by BindingContext from BasePage.  So I think what you're suggesting is to raise a new method from BasePage and define new method OnAppearOnce() that is delcared as public virtual async void OnAppearOnce() from my BasePage ?